# replace apostrophe ' in the middle of the word with \' in java

Tags: java, regex, xpath, backslash, apostrophe

I have an XPath

> //*[@title='ab'cd']

and I want to output it as

> //*[@title='ab\'cd']

I am using this code

```
property = property.replaceAll("^[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)*", "\'");
```

but it is outputting

> //*[@text='ab'cd']

I couldn't find a similar question on StackOverflow.if there is please post the link in the comments.

Comment: Try [`property.replaceAll("\\b'\\b", "\\\\'");`](https://ideone.com/ZhM9KH). Or if you really mean between letters, `.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{L})'(?=\\p{L})", "\\\\'")`

Comment: worked, answer the question and I will accept and upvote. do you know where I can learn this stuff?

Comment: Just so you're aware: the input isn't valid XPath, and the desired output isn't valid XPath either. If you want this as a valid XPath expression in a Java string literal, then for XPath 1.0 you want `//*[@text=\"ab'cd\"]`, while for XPath 2.0 an alternative would be `//*[@text='ab''cd']`

Comment: @MichaelKay how should automate this
//*[@text=''80s']. 
'80s is the text.

Comment: If that's XPath-1.0-embedded-in-Java, use  `"//*[@text=\"'80s\"]"`

Comment: i tried this //*[@text=\"'80s\"] it doesn't work in selenium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace a `'` in between two letters you need a `(?<=\p{L})'(?=\p{L})` regex.

A `(?<=\p{L})` is a positive lookbehind that requires a letter immediately to the left of the current location, and `(?=\p{L})` is a positive lookahead that requires a letter immediately to the right of the current location.

The replacement argument should be `"\\\\'"`, 4 backslashes are necessary to replace with a single backslash.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/rkcPon):

```
String s= "//*[@title='ab'cd']";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{L})'(?=\\p{L})", "\\\\'"));
```

Comment: how should automate this //*[@text=''80s']. '80s is the text.

Comment: Do you have the `//*[@text=''80s']` as a whole input string?

Comment: yes, this is a string i want to convert it to //*[@text=\"'80s\"]

Comment: This does not seem alike. Try [`s.replaceAll("(\\[@\\w+=)'(.*?)']", "$1\"$2\"]")`](http://ideone.com/vN1uKf).