# Regular expression in javascript for accepting only numbers with a comma(,) or a dot(.)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression for accepting only numbers and number with `,` or `.` characters. For example

```
12345--accepted
1.2344 accepted
1,2345 accepted
+123.34@@##sdsd--not accepted
```

I'm using this `/^\d+$/` fot it does not allow `,` or `.` seperators

Comment: what about `...1` , `1,,2345`, `1.2.3`, etc...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match numbers with or without commas and decimals in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text)

Comment: I think you mean `/^\d+[.,]\d+$/`.

Comment: @PranavCBalan this cases must be prevented

Comment: @YCF_L: I did not see the first number due to poor formatting. Besides, the title says "only numbers with , or . characters"

Comment: Nope this is not a valid number

Comment: Actually a number with a comma in it is not a valid number. If you're validating comma's as thousand separators, then this `1,2345` is not valid.

Comment: This is closer to what's needed `^(?:\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex `^\d+([.,]\d+)?$`:

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QiI630/1)

```js
var array = ["12345", "1.2344", "1,2345", "+123.34@@##sdsd"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let regex = /^\d+([.,]\d+)?$/g; 
    var patt = new RegExp(regex);
    console.log(patt.test(array[i]))
}
```

Comment: hi, can you take look at my question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44726427/replace-apostrophe-in-the-middle-of-the-word-with-in-java

Comment: const regPrc = /^\d+([.,]\d+)?$; this is returning me an error that the regular is unterminated

Comment: Guys i'm doing something terribly wrong. I'm writing: const reqPrice = /^\d+([.,]\d+)?$/g; and then if (!reqPrice.test(price)) {
    errors.price = 'Price can contain only numbers!!!';
  } and it does not triggered. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @user7334203 i'm not so familiar with javascript can you try this `const reqPrice = /^\d+([.,]\d+)?$/g; 
if (reqPrice.test('12345')) { 
  console.log('Correct'); 
} else{
  console.log('Not correct'); 
}` i think you miss the else statement

Comment: @YCF_L Ah ok, I won't tell anyone.